# Safari Downloading zip file as "Unknown" on fetch (Using polyfill)

Tags: javascript, go, safari, zip

I set these headers server side (golang snippet) which zips up 16 files in different folders, this all works fine and well in chrome and ff, however doesnt work in safari. Javascript code is below

```
.... 
c.Response().Header().Set("Pragma", "public")
    c.Response().Header().Set("Expires", "0")
    c.Response().Header().Set("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0")
    c.Response().Header().Set("Cache-Control", "public")
    c.Response().Header().Set("Content-Description", "File Transfer")
    c.Response().Header().Set("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
    c.Response().Header().Set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
    c.Response().Header().Set("Content-Lengthg", "177998")
    // header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
    filename := "launchaco.zip"
    // c.Response().Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/file")
    c.Response().Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", filename))

    zw := zip.NewWriter(c.Response())

    header := &zip.FileHeader{
        Name:         "index.html",
        Method:       zip.Store,
        ModifiedTime: uint16(time.Now().UnixNano()),
        ModifiedDate: uint16(time.Now().UnixNano()),
    }
....
```

Javascript

```
fetch(document.location.origin + "/SECRET_ENDPOINT?s=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('structured-elm-todo-state'))))
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.blob();
    }).then(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "download.zip");
        setTimeout(function() {
            var popup = document.getElementById("downloaded-popup");
            popup.className = "downloader-popup downloader-popup__active"
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: here is the actual production site if anyone cares

http://launchaco.com/build/

Comment: What library for saveAs() are you using? This one: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js ?

Comment: Unsure if this is the cause, but there's a typo here: `Content-Lengthg`. Also, have you tried setting `Content-type` to `application/zip`?